# How do I change these producer-consumer microservices to allow parallel processing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, parallel-processing, microservices

I've got a couple microservices (implemented in ruby, although I doubt that is important for my question). One of them provides items, and the other one processes them, and then marks them as processed (via a DELETE call)

The provider has an `/items` endpoint which lists a bunch of items identified with an id, in JSON format. It also has a `DELETE /items/id` endpoint which removes one item from the list (presumably because it is processed)

The code (very simplified) in the "processor" looks like this:

```
items = <GET provider/items>
items.each do |item|
  process item
  <DELETE provider/items/#{item.id}>
end
```

This has several problems, but the one I would like to solve is that it is not thread-safe, and thus I can't run it in parallel. If two workers start processing items simultaneously, they will "step onto each other's toes": they will get the same list of items, and then (try to) process and delete each item twice.

What is the simplest way I can change this setup to allow for parallel processing?

You can assume that I have ruby available. I would prefer keeping changes to a minimum, and would rather not install other gems if possible. [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) is available as a queuing system on the consumer.

Comment: Why do you want to implement such a task queueing system yourself if you have Sidekiq already up and running?

Comment: @PatrickOscity the producer and consumer are on different servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some alternatives (just brainstorming):

1. Just drop HTTP and use pub-sub with a queue. Have the producer queueing items, a number of consumers processing them (and triggering state changes, in this case with HTTP if you fancy it).
2. If you really want to HTTP, I think there are a couple of missing pieces. If your items' states are *pending* and *processed*, there's a hidden/implicit state in your state machine: *in_progress* (or whatever). Once you think of it, picture becomes clearer: your `GET /items` is not idempotent (because it changes the state of items from pending to in progress) and hence should not be a GET in the first place.

   a. an alternative could be adding a new entity (e.g. batch) that gets created via POST and groups some items under it and sends them. Items already returned won't be part of future batches, and then you can mark as done whole batches (e.g. `PUT /batches/X/done`). This gets crazy very fast, as you will start reimplementing features (acks, timeouts, errors) already present both in queueing systems and plain/explicit (see c) HTTP.

   b. a slightly simpler alternative: just turn `/items` in a `POST`/`PUT` (weird in both cases) endpoint that marks items as being processed (and doesn't return them anymore because it only returns pending items). The same issue with errors and timeouts apply though.

   c. have the producer being explicit and requesting the processing of an item to the other service via PUT. you can either include all needed data in the body, or use it as a ping and have the processor requesting the info via GET. you can add asynchronous processing in either side (but probably better in the processor).

I would honestly do 1 (unless compelling reason).

Comment: I ended up doing something more complicated than this, but I think your 2.c answer is the one which solves what I was asking ("the simplest solution which changes the least"). In essence it uses the HTTP protocol as a queue of sorts, which is kind of nice.

Comment: In my case I didn't do 2.c because the amounts of requests between the consumer and the producer would be inverted, and the consumer is the "weak one", performance-wise. It's ok for him to say "I'm finished" as soon as he's done, but a lot of PUTs from the producer could potentially put him down.

Comment: What I ended up doing in reality, in case anyone wonders: The ids on the producer are sequential. I slightly changed the "DELETE" endpoint so that it meant "Delete until" a given ID. I now read the items info in the consumer, put them in the internal queue, and immediately delete all of them from the producer in a single request. Then I process them from the internal consumer queue.

Comment: The "items fetcher" is still not multi-threaded, but the "events processor", which is the slow part, can be done with multiple workers just fine. Also, I've decreased the amount of traffic between the servers, which is also nice.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me that the issue is with parallelizing this implementation is you are thinking that each thread will call:

`<GET provider/items>`

One solution would be to get all the items first then do the async processing.

My Ruby is non-existent but it might look something like this:

```
class HardWorker
    include Sidekiq::Worker
    def perform(item)
        process item
        <DELETE provider/items/#{item.id}>
    end
end

items = <GET provider/items>

items.each do |item|
    HardWorker.perform_async(item)
end
```

This way your "producer" is the loop and the consumer is the async `HardWorker`.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid that solution alone is not enough. Imagine there are 200 items. The first GET gets the 200 and starts processing them via the Hardworker. When it has processed around 100, a new GET index is launched. It gets the 100 pending items, so there are Hardworkers duplicated for those.

Comment: That said, what I ended up doing is similar to your proposal in essence: I "read the items" and then "process them in a different worker". The thing that was missing was "removing all of the read items in one go". See my comments in @porras answer for details. In any case, +1 for the idea of using a worker inside the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the simplest way I can change this setup to allow for parallel processing?

If you can upgrade the code on the server, or add middle-man code, then the simplest way is a queue.

If you prefer just client-side, with no middle-man and no client-to-client talk, and some occasional redundancy is ok, then here are some ideas.

1. Reduce collisions by using shuffle

   - If it's ok for your server to receive a DELETE for a non-existent object
   - And the "process item" cost+time is relatively small
   - And the process is order-independent
   - Then you could shuffle the items to reduce collisions:

     ```
     items.shuffle.each do |item|
       process item
     ```
2. Check that the item exists by using HEAD

   - If your server has the HEAD method
   - And has a way to look up one item
   - And the HTTP connection is cheap+fast compared to "process item"
   - Then you could skip the item if it doesn't exists:

     ```
     items.each do |item|
       next if !<HEAD provider/items/id>
     ```
3. Refresh the items by using a polling loop

   - If the items are akin to you polling an ongoing pool of work
   - And are order independent
   - And the GET request is idempotent, i.e. it's ok to request all the items more than once
   - And the DELETE request returns a result that informs you the item did not exist
   - Then you could process items until you hit a redundancy, then refresh the items list:

     ```
     loop do
       items = <GET provider/items>
       if items.blank?
         sleep 1
         next
       end
       items.each do |item|
         process item
         <DELETE provider/items/#{item.id}>
         break if DELETE returns a code that indicates "already deleted"
       end
     end
     ```
4. All of the above combined using a polling loop, shuffle, and HEAD check.

   - This is surprisingly efficient, given no queue, nor middle-man, nor client-to-client talk.
   - There's still a rare redundant "process item" that can happen when multiple clients check if an item exists then start processing it; in practice this is near-zero probability, especially when there are many items.

     ```
     loop do
       items = <GET provider/items>
       if items.blank?
         sleep 1 
         next
       end
       items.shuffle do |item|
         break if !<HEAD provider/items/id>
         process item
         <DELETE provider/items/#{item.id}>
         break if DELETE returns a code that indicates "already deleted"
       end
     end
     ```

Comment: Hi, I ended up doing something completely different from what you suggested (see my comments to @porras solution), but I'll keep shuffle in mind for other applications. +1